# How to open an Excel workbook that ends with a specific string using Applescript

Tags: applescript, ms-office

I am new to Applescript and I am trying to open a `xlsx` file that ends like DK.xlsx. Tried using the following code, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

```
set sourcefilepath to "Macintosh HD:Users:nprabu:Documents:Work:Project:Q1 2018:"

set sourcefile to name of every file of sourcefilepath whose name ends with "DK.xlsx"

tell application "Microsoft Excel"

    open workbook workbook file name sourcefile

end tell
```

Comment: Why don’t you use Finders search function?

Comment: Before attempting to open `sourcefile`, why not try to output the name of `sourcefile` to see what's being assigned?  A window dialog box would be sufficient and it's just for debugging purposes.

Comment: @nprabu Did you manage to get it sorted ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're new to AppleScript and because the script you gave had myriad rudimentary errors, this answer is quite long as I thought it appropriate to explain how to correct the script and why the errors arose in the first place.

However, for the benefit of any readers for whom this would be **TL;DR**, here are <strike>two</strike> three versions of the script in their complete form, each differing in how file(s) are sought and the command sent to *Excel* in order to open it/them.

**Disclaimer:**  I haven't been able to fully test the scripts, as I do not own a copy of *Microsoft Excel*.  I have formulated these snippets based on an [online version of the AppleScript dictionary](https://applescriptlibrary.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/excel-2004-applescript-reference.pdf).  If you encounter any script errors, your feedback will help me correct them.

① This version uses the `open workbook` command as per your original script, which only accepts a single file reference.  Therefore, the search conducted will return whichever single file it finds first with the appropriate filename ending.  ***Note:*** See below for why the *Excel* command might not work, and why I have provided a second version of the script should this be the case:

```
    set sourcefilepath to "Macintosh HD:Users:nprabu:Documents:Work:Project:Q1 2018:"

    try
        tell application "Finder" to set sourcefile to ¬
            (the first file in the folder sourcefilepath whose ¬
                name ends with "DK.xlsx") as text
    on error
        return display notification ¬
            "No filenames ending in \"DK.xlsx\"" with title "File Not Found"
    end try

    tell application "Microsoft Excel" to ¬
        open workbook workbook file name sourcefile
```

② This version uses the standard `open` command that accepts one or more `file` or `alias` objects.  Use this version if you need to open multiple files easily or the above version of the script fails to open the file:

```
    set sourcefilepath to "Macintosh HD:Users:nprabu:Documents:Work:Project:Q1 2018:"

    tell application "Finder" to set sourcefiles to ¬
        (every file in the folder sourcefilepath whose ¬
            name ends with "DK.xlsx") as alias list

    if sourcefiles is {} then return display notification ¬
        "No filenames ending in \"DK.xlsx\"" with title "File Not Found"

    tell application "Microsoft Excel" to open the sourcefiles
```

**③ Addendum: Emergency Script:**

Thanks to [@user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894) for testing these scripts and reporting some odd behaviour from *Microsoft Excel* regarding how it responds to the standard `open` command (see the comments thread attached to this answer).

Essentially, it behaves as expected if *Excel* is not already running, and will open multiple files (in the background).  However, if *Excel* is already open, it will only open one file out of a given file list, and the one it chooses to open is seemingly random.

Therefore, I'm adding this third version of the script as a less graceful approach to opening multiple files, but one that will surely cope with *Excel*'s personality issues:

```
    set sourcefilepath to "Macintosh HD:Users:nprabu:Documents:Work:Project:Q1 2018:"

    tell application "Finder" to set sourcefiles to ¬
        (every file in the folder sourcefilepath whose ¬
            name ends with "DK.xlsx") as alias list

    if sourcefiles is {} then return display notification ¬
        "No filenames ending in \"DK.xlsx\"" with title "File Not Found"

    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        activate -- Bring Excel into focus

        -- This loops through the list of files and
        -- opens them one at a time
        repeat with sourcefile in sourcefiles
            open the sourcefile
        end repeat
    end tell
```

You can, of course, try and replace `open the sourcefile` with `open workbook workbook file name (sourcefile as text)`, should that command be working in your version, but otherwise you'll be fine just using `open`.

---

### A Detailed Breakdown

#### Retrieving your file(s)

The first few errors in your original script arise from this line:

```
set sourcefile to name of every file of sourcefilepath ¬
    whose name ends with "DK.xlsx"
```

*(I have split the code over two lines for readability; this doesn't affect how AppleScript executes the commands.)*

▸ Firstly, this command needs to be sent to an application that can handle file and folder objects.  The two options you have are **Finder** and **System Events**.  *Finder* is suitable and most commonly used for file commands.  To send a command to *Finder*, you simply add a `tell` clause at the start of the line:

```
tell application "Finder" to set sourcefile to ¬
    name of every file of folder sourcefilepath ¬
    whose name ends with "DK.xlsx"
```

You also need to specify that `sourcefilepath` is a folder object, which I've done by adding the object specifier `folder` in front of the variable.

▸ Your question as it is stated, together with your choice of AppleScript variable name, implies you are wanting a single file to be opened.  However, the command we've just been looking at tells *Finder* to get `every file`, which will always return a **list** of items (although it may be a list containing only one item), rather than a single item.  If there are multiple files whose names end with "DK.xlsx", then all of them will be returned in this list.  This will cause problems when it comes to opening the files using *Excel*'s `open workbook` command, which can only handle one file per command statement.

If you are reasonably sure there's only one filename that ends in "DK.xlsx", then you can change `every` to `first`:

```
tell application "Finder" to set sourcefile to ¬
    the name of the first file of folder sourcefilepath ¬
    whose name ends with "DK.xlsx"
```

*(I prefixed some terms with `the` to make it more readable; AppleScript happily copes with or without `the` being present.)*

The other consideration is that `open workbook` requires that the full path to the file be specified.  However, by requesting that *Finder* returns just the `name` of the file(s), you will only be given the filenames without the path.  In order to retrieve the full path, remove the request for the file's `name` property and instead retrieve the file object, which you can then coerce into text:

```
tell application "Finder" to set sourcefile to ¬
    (the first file of folder sourcefilepath ¬
    whose name ends with "DK.xlsx") as text
```

▸ If it turns out that you do, indeed, wish to retrieve multiple files that end in the suffix "DK", then its best to coerce the **list** of file objects into an `alias list` (which is a list of aliases).  This is so we can use the standard `open` command instead of `open workbook`, as the former can accept a list of multiple file aliases, enabling you to open many files with one single command.

```
tell application "Finder" to set sourcefile to ¬
    (every file of folder sourcefilepath ¬
    whose name ends with "DK.xlsx") as alias list
```

#### Opening the file(s) in *Excel*

You didn't mention which version of *Microsoft Excel* you're using, which may turn out to be pertinent information.  [This](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/applescript-cant-tell-excel-to-open-a-workbook.650827/) forum question from 2009 is from a user who reports running into trouble when using the `open workbook` command.

▸ **BUT...**  Let's assume for now that the command **will** work with your version, and that you only wish to open a single file.  The syntax as you've got it is all correct, and the adjustment I mentioned above to retrieve the full file path will prevent the `open workbook` command from throwing an error because of a bad file reference.  One stylistic note: you can write the `tell` statement and the `open workbook` command on a single line, then delete the `end tell` line:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel" to open workbook workbook file name sourcefile
```

No one form is better than the other, so it's personal choice.

▸ The forum post I mentioned above that reported a malfunctioning `open workbook` command also cited the same problem when using the standard `open` command.  However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692707/open-file-in-excel-2016-using-applescript) Stack Overflow post provides the likely cause, and reassures me that this `open` command will work where the `open workbook` command may not.

Basically, in the same way that the *Finder* application needs a folder object to be specified explicitly as being a `folder`, *Excel* needs the file object to be specified explicitly as being a `file` (or `alias`):

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel" to open file sourcefile
```

▸ The benefit of this `open` command is that it can accept lists of aliases to open many files at once.  Therefore, if you decide to keep the version of the *Finder* command that retrieves multiple files, make sure you coerce it to an `alias list`, which you can then use like so:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel" to open sourcefile
```

Note here that the `file` object specifier is absent when opening multiple files, because the variable `sourcefile` is already of the correct type, namely `alias list`.

#### Closing comments

The final versions of the script I supplied at the beginning are *slightly* different in how I chose to implement the changes I've detailed here.  I also felt it wise to include some basic error-handling in case a file could not be found, which would throw an error and might lead you to wonder if the code was faulty.

If you find that the file successfully opens in *Excel*, but that it remains in the background concealed behind other applications, you can add this command to the script to bring *Excel* into the foreground and make it the focussed application:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel" to activate
```

or—combining it with the existing *Excel* commands:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    open file sourcefile
end tell
```

---

If you need any of this clarified or if you have any further minor questions relating to this, leave a comment and I'll get back to you.  If you find this helpful or if it solves your problem, do consider selecting this answer or any other that proves more useful so other forum visitors know this issue has been addressed and can benefit from it if they have a similar problem.

Comment: This may be an Excel version issue, however with ② when Excel is already open, it only opens one of the files in the `list` and not necessarily the first file. With Excel still opened, if you close the one file in the list it opened and run the script again it opens a different file but again only one file in the list, and so on. Which comes off as really strange behavior. Using a `repeat` _loop_ on the `list` is a workaround.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for testing that for me.  I tested it with other apps, such as *TextEdit* and *Keynote* (both Apple apps, mind you), and it did what I expected and wanted it to do.  That’s a shame that *Excel* isn’t conforming.  Looks like I’ll *have* to use a `repeat` loop.  By the way, how does it behave when *Excel* isn’t already open ?  Is *Excel* one of those apps that insists I `activate` it first ?

Comment: With Excel closed and testing with a 3 file list, it opens all three, and Excel is in the background unless `activate` is used.

Comment: JSYK Your updated version ③  and the optional "replace `open the source file` with `open workbook workbook file name (source file as text)`" works. +1 for an excellent answer!

Comment: @CJK, Thank you so much for such a detailed answer, this helps a lot. I tested all the three options that you have provided and they work as expected. I am using Excel 2016 version. Thanks again.